# Type mismatch error with range array; transpose intersect logic

Tags: excel, vba

1. How can I resolve the type mismatch error (indicated)?
2. If I want to *restrict* the sub to the specified ranges, why would changing `If Not Intersect` to `If Intersect` exit the sub?

   ```
   Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal sH As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
       ' Exclude specified ranges
       Dim rExcl(1) As Range, i As Integer, r As Range
       Set rExcl(0) = Range("Table1"): Set rExcl(1) = Range("Table2")
       For i = 0 To 1
           For Each r In rExcl(i)
               If r.Parent Is sH Then
                   If Not Intersect(Target, r) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub    ' Type mismatch error
               End If
           Next
       Next
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: I created two named ranges of workbook scope and added the code to the `ThisWorkbook` module. No error on my end. Are those ranges may be also ranges of `Excel` tables (listobjects?

Comment: @VBasic2008: Even if Tables, they have to behave similarly. Only some other objects, named as `Tablexxx` could produce such a behavior, I think.

Comment: @FaneDuru It does not seem to be other object type named as `Table1` or `Table2`, because that  would have triggered an error in this line `Set rExcl(0) = Range("Table1"): Set rExcl(1) = Range("Table2")`

Comment: @EEM: What you say looks to be right, but practically the error which the OP mentioned in his question **could not appear if a range is involved**. I could not reproduce it. I cannot imagine what of a range can determine such an error, neither... Even an error on the analyzed cell will not produce it. I think we can understand something only if he would like to share the involved workbook...

Comment: I have isolated the code in the [attached workbook](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00370496940624477465); the error happens on double-clicking the highlighted cell.

Comment: There is a conflict in your workbook. There is the Workbook even you show us in the question and another `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` event which tries **closing the Excel application** if the double clicked cell is the one you claim as being 'strange'... Please, read the edited answer and try doing as I recommended.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works without any problem **in the way you presented** and it will also work in the way you try understanding, but with a different meaning, respectively:

You should understand that `Intersect` returns a 'Range' and the above code checks if this `Range` exists. In words, this part should be understood as "If the two ranges are intersecting".

This part `If Intersect(Target, r) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` means "If the two ranges are not intersecting" (such an eventual intersection does not exist).

No any 'Type mismatch' should exist in both mentioned variants, if you are referring to real tables. It may appear **if you named a different object (not a range) as 'TableX'**...

Please, try inserting the next code line:

```
Debug.Print TypeOf rExcl(0) Is Range, TypeOf rExcl(1) Is Range: stop
```

after:

```
Set rExcl(0) = Range("Table1"): Set rExcl(1) = Range("Table2")
```

What does it return in Immediate Window?

**Edited**:

You could not 'reproduce the error in Debug.Print' because that line is not even reached...

There is a conflict in your workbook. There is the Workbook event you show us in the question and another `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` event which tries **closing the Excel application** if the double clicked cell is the one you claim as being 'strange'...

The sheet event is triggered first and the Workbook one is not triggered anymore, since the code tries quitting Excel application. Try put `Exit Sub` as the first code line in the Worksheet event and try the double click again.

Nothing wrong will happen after that...

Comment: I could not reproduce the error when I inserted the debug; I have posted a workbook (above).

Comment: @user2319146: I downloaded the workbook and made some tests. I edited my answer and explained what is happening in your workbook. Please, check what I suggested and send some feedback.

Comment: Inserting `Exit Sub` would disable the Worksheet event, which I do not want to do.

Comment: @user2319146: But, if you not want doing that and want to quit Excel, in case of double click on that cell, you should escape it in the `Workbook` event: `If Range("Table1").Parent Is sH And Target.Address = "$G$1" Then Exit Sub`. I suggested `Exit Sub` only to test that the second similar event was the cause of the problem...

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the purpose of the code posted is to validate if the user `double-clicked` a `cell` within any of the Tables (i.e.: `Table1` or `Table2`), if so then `Exit Sub`.

In regards to the questions:

*1. How can I resolve the type mismatch error (indicated)?*
`If Not Intersect(Target, r) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub    ' Type mismatch error`
Unfortunately, this error cannot be reproduced. This error is triggered when the data type of a variable differs to what is required. In this case it seems *"almost"* impossible because:

- [Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.intersect) expects ranges and both variables *(`Target` and `r`)* are defined as ranges.
- `Intersect` returns an object *(`range`)* which is what `Is Nothing` is expecting.
- `Intersect` could also return an `Error` when the ranges have different parents, but that situation is already taken care by this line `If r.Parent Is Sh Then`.

  The proposed solution includes a method to debug this error when it happens.

*2. If I want to restrict the sub to the specified ranges, why would changing `If Not Intersect` to `If Intersect` exit the sub?*
This is happening because the code posted is validating the ranges `cell` by `cell`, therefore if the user `double-clicked` the last cell of the `table` then the code compares the first cell and because there is no intersection the code exits the sub.
Bear in mind that the purpose is to validate if the `double-clicked` `cell` belongs or not to any of the tables ( i.e.: *“ranges intersection”*, if one cell intersect or not with a range, then the entire range intersects or not), as such there is no need to validate each cell, instead validate the entire range at once.

**Proposed Solution:**
Note that the `ERR_Intersect` subroutine should be just temporary, it is include to help analyze the mismatch error.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim rExcl(1) As Range, vRng As Variant
    
    Set rExcl(0) = Range("Table1")
    Set rExcl(1) = Range("Table2")

    For Each vRng In rExcl
            
        Rem Validate Worksheet
        If vRng.Parent Is Sh Then
                        
        Rem Validate Target
        On Error Resume Next
        If Not Intersect(Target, vRng) Is Nothing Then
            blErr = Error.Number <> 0
            On Error GoTo 0
            If blErr Then GoTo ERR_Intersect
            Exit Sub
    
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        
    End If: Next

Exit Sub

ERR_Intersect:    
    Debug.Print vbLf; "Error: "; Err.Number; " - "; Err.Description
    Debug.Print "Object"; Tab(11); "TypeName"; Tab(21); "Address"; Tab(31); "Parent"
    Debug.Print "Target"; Tab(11); TypeName(Target);
    Debug.Print Tab(21); Target.Address(0, 0);
    Debug.Print Tab(31); Target.Parent.Name;
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "vRng"; Tab(11); TypeName(vRng);
    Debug.Print Tab(21); vRng.Address(0, 0);
    Debug.Print Tab(31); vRng.Parent.Name;
    Debug.Print
    MsgBox "Error: " & Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description & vbLf & _
        vbTab & "See Immediate Window for details."
    Exit Sub

    End Sub
```

Comment: I could not reproduce the error when I substituted your code; I have posted a workbook (above). For (2), what specific change do I need to make, please?